# Использование Phantom Reference вместо переопределения метода finalize

Tags: java, jdbc

Разбираюсь в исходниках jdbc драйвера mysql. Наткнулся на то, что в классе `com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver` при создании соединения создается phantom reference. Эти ссылки потом обрабатываются в фоновом потоке. Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем использовать такую сложную логику, если можно просто переопределить метод `finalize()` в классе `com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу сам, в результате небольшого расследования выяснил следующее:

Ранее в `jdbc` драйвере `mysql` для закрытия соединений использовался метод `finalize()`. Но от него отказались ввиду "ужасной" неэффективности. Более подробно об этом написано в [release notes](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,559877,559877). Особо любопытные могут посмотреть [коммит](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/commit/44547582c5e301254ae85f9ad4b303f1513fa913).

Остается вопрос, почему `finalize()` не эффективен. Как я понял, он выполняется в потоке gс вызывающим у объектов методы `finalize()`. `PhantomReference` же, обрабатывает ссылки в отдельном потоке, за счет этого происходит некоторый выйгрыш, т.к. не замедляется общий процесс сборки и объекты "требующие большего внимания" обрабатываются раньше, а не стоят вместе с остальными объектами в очереди.

Проверить этом можно следующим тестом:

```
public class Solution {
    private static final LongAdder increment = new LongAdder();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         int count = 1_000_000;

         //накидываем работы для gc
         Collection trash = getSimpleObjects(count);
         trash.clear();
         //создаем объекты с фантомными ссылками
         Collection<Object> objects = getObjectsPhantomReferences(count);
         long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
         objects.clear();
         System.gc();
         while (increment.longValue() != count) ;
         System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

         increment.reset();
         //немного ждем
         TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);

        //накидываем работы для gc
        trash = getSimpleObjects(count);
        trash.clear();
        //создаем объекты с переопределенными методом finalize()
        objects = getObjectsWithFinalize(count);
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        objects.clear();
        System.gc();
        while (increment.longValue() != count);

        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
   }


   private static Collection<Object> getSimpleObjects(int count) {
        Collection<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
           objects.add(new Object());

        return objects;
   }

   private static Collection<Object> getObjectsWithFinalize(int count) {
        Collection<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
           objects.add(new Object() {
               @Override
               public void finalize() throws Throwable {
                  super.finalize();
                  Solution.finalize(this);
               }
           });

        return objects;
   }

   private static Collection<Object> getObjectsPhantomReferences(int count) {
        Collection<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           Object obj = new Object();
           objects.add(obj);
           Cleaner.create(obj, () -> finalize(null));
        }

        return objects;
    }

    private static void finalize(Object o) {
       increment.increment();
    }
}
```

Очевидно, что тест неточен, т.к. `System.gc()` может вызвать сборку мусора с некоторой задержкой, если вообще вызовет.